# Почему хранимая процедура при вызове из C# кода выполняется в 18 раз дольше чем на сервере?

Tags: c#, sql, производительность

Есть хранимая процедура в MS SQL базе. В SQL Server Managment Studio она выполняется всего за 10 секунд. Но если я запускаю эту же процедуру из C# (ASP.NET), то время выполнения почему-то увеличивается до 180 секунд!

Вот такой примерно код используется для вызова этой процедуры:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
{
   connection.ConnectionString = "XXXX";
   string procedure = "dbo.sp_ProcedureName";

   using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(procedure, connection))
   {
      command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      command.CommandTimeout = XXX;

      connection.Open();
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
```

В чем может быть причина? Почему так сильно увеличилось время выполнения и как это можно исправить или минимизировать?

p.s. База на том же сервере стоит, что и код, при обращении к удаленному, длительность увеличивается секунд на 12.

Comment: Сеть? Передача большого объема данных?

Comment: Покажите вашу процедуру, Что вы ей передаете? Что она делает?

Comment: @Viktorov  Данные не передаются, вызов без параметров, в процедуре вызываются 5 других процедур, что-то типа:
 exec dbo._sp1 
 exec dbo._sp2
 exec dbo._sp3
 exec dbo._sp4
 exec dbo._sp5

Comment: @tym32167 база на том же сервере что и код, данные не передаются, просто вызов процедуры без параметров, получать назад мне тоже ничего не нужно, только результат, что выполнилась успешно

Comment: Вот что выдает SQL Server Managment Studio при запуске процедуры непосредственно в ней:

(затронута одна строка)
(затронуто строк: 2611)
(затронуто строк: 1393)
(затронута одна строка)
(затронута одна строка)
 и т.д. Всего порядка 30 срок.

Comment: Тогда действительно странно. Попробуйте воспользоваться SQL Profiler'ом, чтобы понять где задержка

Comment: @tym32167 Кстати, я как то видел похожую проблему, но у MySQL сервера, суть ее была в том, что нужно было включить skip_name_resolve опцию, но в MS SQL вроде такого нет, так что буду пробовать профилировать тогда.

Comment: Есть такая легендарная статья [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) (есть перевод на русский).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По совету пользователя Alexander Petrov начал знакомиться со статьей  Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS, внес небольшое изменение в хранимую процедуру и время выполнения стало практическое такое же как во время выполнения в SQL Server Managment Studio, сократившись со 180 сек. до 13.

Попробую объяснить, как я это понял, и если ошибаюсь, поправьте пожалуйста. Итак, тормозило все из-за того, что в внутри основной процедуры сначала вычислялся параметр, а потом этот параметр использовался для вызова других 5 процедур. Удалось отказаться от вычисляемого параметра в пользу константы и SQL смог оптимально построить план выполнения для вызываемых процедур. А в Managment Studio это значения вычислялось в процессе выполнения и план так же создавался "на лету", отсюда и более быстрое выполнение. Буду копать дальше, т.к. не всегда будет возможность отказаться от вычисляемого параметра.

Comment: Ха, прикол в том, что я ради эксперимента вернул все как было, т. е. вычисляемую переменную вместо константы, и что удивительно скорость выполнения осталась такая же. Похоже план закешировался, и поскольку вычисляемое значение осталось такое же, то сервер решил не создавать новый план, а использовать старый, пока не изменится переменная.

Comment: Это называется parameter sniffing. Чинится расстановкой хинта optimize for unknown или точечными фиксами типов джойнов